# Laravel many to many relationships sync() where

Tags: laravel, orm, relationship

with laravel 5.2,I have 2 models called order and worker (Many to Many relationship)

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and ..

```
    public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withTimestamps();
}
```

the pivot table cantains field called assignment 
id | order_id | worker_id | assignment

I need to sync() where the assignment field is reassigned ..

```
            $order->workers()->where('assignment','Reassigned')->sync($workers);
```

that does not work ..

Comment: I don't understand, what is the content of the `$workers` variable

Comment: array from the request

Comment: @HosMercury: Can you show your `$workers` array

Comment: $workers = $request->worker; // [2,3,5] like so

Comment: @HosMercury: So, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to sync() workers id only when assignment field == "Reassigned"

Comment: @HosMercury: You mean, you want only records with assignment field == 'Reassigned' to stay and others should be deleted in the pivot table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `withPivotValue` function in model relation 
like

```
public function workersReassigned()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->withPivotValue('assignment','Reassigned');
}


public function workersAnyThingElse()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->withPivotValue('assignment','AnyThingElse');
}
```

and then call `Sync` function as usual you call it

```
 $order->workersReassigned()->sync($workers);
 $order->workersAnyThingElse()->sync($workers);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works and this is also the proper way to do it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Don't know  will it work or not (not available test it right now), but try `wherePivot` [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_wherePivot)

```
 $order->workers()->wherePivot('assignment', 'Reassigned')->sync($workers);
```

Comment: Did you add `withPivot` to your relations? `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('assignment')->withTimestamps();`

Comment: try set operator directly `wherePivot('assignment', '=', 'Reassigned')`

Answer (score 1):

**If you have pivot variables:**

Relationship if you have pivot variables:

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('value', 'value2');
}
```

$workers array:

```
$workers[$order_id] = [
    ... // your pivot variables
    'value'         => $value,
    'created_at'    => $created_at,
    'updated_at'    => $updated_at,
]
```

**If you don't have pivot variables send and array of orders id's**

```
 $order->workers()->where('assignment','Reassigned')->sync([1,2,3]);
```

**Edit:**

Try with the where clausule in a new function

```
public function workersReassigned()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->where('assignment','Reassigned')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('value', 'value2');
}
```

And after:

```
 $order->workersReassigned()->sync($workers);
```

Comment: It doesnt work.. you give me an idea about withPivot .. but where()->sync() not work

Comment: I used query builder to solve it , but hope to use elequent

Comment: I've updated my answer, try with the where in a new function